# How to trace token transfer that may contained in contract inner transactions

Tags: transactions, erc-20, internal-transactions

Take this [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x97e20747e4f8fffa66b4fa0b0ff039a115713f692f5f47869e004c4f344bd041) as an example.
This single transaction contains 50 inner transactions.

If directly calling [api](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0x97e20747e4f8fffa66b4fa0b0ff039a115713f692f5f47869e004c4f344bd041), what we get is a very long raw hex in `input` field. This input actually contains the contract method info and the method params. And it seems that the contract method is actually a batch transfer, but the creator does not provide the full code.

Here comes the issue, if I need to monitor this token transfer by code, how can I deal with this kind of transfer? As everyone can create new contract, do I need to trace all contracts that deal with this kind of token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special.

These type of bulk sending contracts will still emit the regular ERC20 standard `Transfer` event. All you need is a program that searches for these events in transaction logs, the same as you would for a single erc20 transfer tx.

Both parity and geth support a log filter, which can be accessed through web3 as well.

Comment: `eth_getTransactionReceipt` together with `event` and `log` is a great help

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of ways:

1. Use `truffle-contract` to get contract code and subscribe to events (in your case - `Transfer`). Truffle-Contract automatically decode logs to readable format. Cons: you have to use Truffle infrastructure to compile code and get contract at address.
2. Time ago I used code from `truffle-contract` that responsible for transaction log decoding. Unfortunately it was done for closed source project, but I definitely remember I reversed it from [decodeLogs](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/blob/develop/dist/truffle-contract.js#L46) method, suppose you can try to do the same - extract this method with all dependencies and feed it with your raw transaction log data and get something readable.